# how can use countless rows of query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a command that returns the unknown number of rows from query to the output.
I put every single of columns in an array
this is command:

```
$job_list = mysql_query("SELECT
     t2.job_name,
     t2.job_category,
     t2.job_grup, 
    FROM tbl_job t1, tbl_job2 t2
        WHERE t1.user_id = '$userid' AND
    t1.job_name     = t2.job_name AND
    t1.job_category = t2.job_category AND 
    t1.job_grup     = t2.job_grup");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($job_want_list)) {

$name[]     =$row['job_name'];
$category[] =$row['job_category'];
$grup[]     =$row['job_grup'];
}
```

Now how can i echo them all without having to call one at a time?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to echo `$name`, `$category` and `$grup` (perhaps `$group`?) at the same time?

Comment: no, i can get name with $name[0..1...] i want to put one by one in a table whith out calling one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct to iterate each element in `$name` array.

An example:

```
foreach ($name as $job_name)
{
    echo $job_name.', ';
}
```

And you don't need to worry how many rows you will get from database (just make sure `$name` is at least declared as array (`$name = [];`) to prevent warning`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` from popping up).

UPDATE:

Since you want to show values from all 3 variables, then you can do such thing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $name[$i] . '<br>';
    echo 'Category: ' . $category[$i] . '<br>';
    echo 'Group: ' . $grup[$i] . '<br>';
}
```

*One note: I would change the name to `$group` instead of leaving `$grup`.*

Comment: I want to print each of the (name - group - category) in a single form. some thing like this:https://image.ibb.co/hSkF5m/Untitled.png

Comment: I see. Then the approach would be slightly different.